# Wordpress - ajax request to custom php script

Tags: php, wordpress

I have problem with my e-mail form in Wordpress. I create a custom form and add jQuery script to send ajax request. When i fill form and click Submit, then form returned me error 404. Ajax send post request to contact.php file, but my script can't find this file.

I add contact.php file to root Wordpress directory and my theme directory, but i have this same error i.e

```
http://domainname/contact.php not found
```

Of course file contact.php exist in root directory.

My request code:

```
function onSubmit(token) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'contact.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: $('#contact').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            if (response.success == true) {
                $('#contact-form').modal('hide');
            } else {
                alert(response.msg);
            }

            grecaptcha.reset();
        },
        error: function() {
            $('#form-error-modal').modal('show');

            grecaptcha.reset();
        }
    });
};
```

I try other solution, but still the same. All works when i move contact.php script to external server without wordpress, but for me is not solution.

Any idea, how i can solved this problem?

Comment: If you get a 404 error it's likely due to one of two things: 1. You have the wrong path for the file or  2. You have a webserver setting or .htaccess setting that is giving you the 404.

Comment: Hi @Azer i think it's a problem with .htaccess, path to contact.php file is ok.

Comment: Depending on your setup, WordPress, or a security plugin, might be blocking you from opening custom scripts inside the root folder. Try creating a subfolder and place the script in there. Might work.

Answer (score 0):

Add full url to file, not only `contact.php`. But better use [wordpres ajax](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Or

```
function onSubmit(token) {
    $.ajax({
        url: ajax_init.ajax_url,
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
          action : 'custom_contact_form',
          form   : $('#contact').serialize()
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            if (response.success == true) {
                $('#contact-form').modal('hide');
            } else {
                alert(response.msg);
            }
            grecaptcha.reset();
        },
        error: function() {
            $('#form-error-modal').modal('show');
            grecaptcha.reset();
        }
    });
};
```

in your enqueue function:

```
  wp_localize_script('your-handle', 'ajax_init', array(
      'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php') 
    )
  );
```

here processing request

```
add_action('wp_ajax_custom_contact_form', 'custom_contact_form');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_contact_form', 'custom_contact_form'); // Allow front-end submission

function custom_contact_form() {
  $form = $_REQUEST['form'];
  parse_str($form, $post);
  // your logic here
}
```

Comment: Hi Sky :) Thanks for answer. I add full url to ajax request but i have this same error with 404. I think the only solution will be custom plugin.